# How do I avoid duplicate/similar mod_rewrite rules?

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have a number of URIs that read as follows;

1. http://www.domain.com/index.php?route=information/information&information_id=2 (about)
2. http://www.domain.com/index.php?route=information/information&information_id=4 (help)
3. http://www.domain.com/index.php?route=information/information&information_id=7 (contact)
4. ....

Is there a way I could avoid writing explicit but similar rewrite rules?

**EXAMPLE**

```
 RewriteRule    ^contact$    index.php?route=information/information&information_id=2    [NC,L]    # About

 RewriteRule    ^help$    index.php?route=information/information&information_id=4    [NC,L]    # Help
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of possibilities.  Easiest might be something like this:

```
^(.*)$ index.php?route=information/information&information_id=$1
```

Then handle the `information_id` *string* in your `index.php`.  Make sure it only allows acceptable values and 404s everything else.

Or to be more restrictive at the `mod_rewrite` level:

```
^(contact|help|foo)$ index.php?route=information/information&information_id=$1
```

Comment: Thanks Madbreaks. When you say `handle` the string in the `index.php`, what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than a handful of pages to rewrite, the key is a to have a single, simple rewrite rule combined with logic in your index page to serve the correct content based on the URL requested.

Take a look at the .htaccess and index.php for any popular CMS which supports url rewriting and you will find what you seek.